# Count occurrences of list elements in an expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elements and a large expression in these elements. I would like to count the occurrences of each of the list elements in the expression. Say, the list is `{a1,a2,a3,...,an}` and the expression is
 `2a1 - 3a2^2*a5 - 7x^2 a4 + 3a1*a4 + ...` so the output would be something like

> {{a1,2},{a2,1},{a3,0},{a4,2},...}.

I have tried to use `Count` and `Select`, but am not getting the required results. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = 2 a1 - 3 a2^2*a5 - 7 x^2 a4 + 3 a1*a4;
lst = {a1, a2, a3, a4}; 

Transpose[{lst, Lookup[Counts[Level[expr, {-1}]], lst, 0]}]
```

> {{a1, 2}, {a2, 1}, {a3, 0}, {a4, 2}}

or

```
Transpose[{lst, Count[Level[expr, {-1}], #] & /@ lst}]
```

> {{a1, 2}, {a2, 1}, {a3, 0}, {a4, 2}}